# Update toggle button's appearance (with style set in xaml) in code not working

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I've several flat toggle buttons in my application and they inherit the same style as below:

```
<Style x:Key="TButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC7C7C7"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFCFCFCF" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

After I did certain updates (e.g when a process is carried out, TButton.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue, it worked), I want to change back the toggle button to its original look, but it is not working. Here's how I change the style back to the original:

```
TButton.Style = (Style)FindResource("TButtonStyle");
```

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem? Is it because of "StaticResource"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are assigning the background color in code while doing the processing, it gets higher precedence than your style.

Clear the background color property to reset it

```
TButton.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
```